# ScrollView in AbsoluteLayout doesn't leave room for button below

Tags: xamarin.forms

I getting a conception problem to display correctly the page. I want to have on the bottom of the page a button. I used to do it, AbsoluteLayout.
For some of the screens that are small, all the information doesn't appear so I had to activate the ScrollView.
But the ScrollView doesn't make the job as I would like, a part of the information is still "eaten" by the bottom button. (See the image)

[image]

There is the code :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout>
                       **** Some code *****
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        
        <Button AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 1, 1, 40" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional"
                ... some more code .../>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I think the way I want to make it is not correct. what can I do to make it display correctly?

Comment: You've told the scrollview to use the entire content area, so it does. But IMHO rather than try to fix its AbsoluteLayout declaration, just stop using AbsoluteLayout - its making the job harder. Replace it with `<Grid RowDeclarations="*,Auto">` Then make Scrollview Grid.Row=0 and Button Grid.Row=1.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks a lot. Can you please give your answer below so that I can validate it as the good one :)

Comment: Go ahead and accept Guangyu's answer. (Its good to have complete code, and I didn't want to take the time to do that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as Steve said, using Grid is better than AbsoluteLayout. I made a demo and it works well.

```
    <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" >
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
    
            <Button Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Suggested Improvements to answer: **1)** `<RowDefinition></RowDefinition>`: its true that default is `*`, but IMHO its better to be explicit. And having a separate close tag is unnecessary: `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` **2)** Even better, do these concisely as a property inside the Grid tag: `<Grid RowDefinitions="*,40">`.